# Property in Cell Factory

Tags: javafx

Hi I have a little problem in this Cell Factory :

```
private Callback<TableColumn<Member, String>,
        TableCell<Member, String>> setPhotoCellFactory() {

    Callback<TableColumn<Member, String>, TableCell<Member, String>> callback = new Callback<TableColumn<Member, String>, TableCell<Member, String>>() {
        @Override
        public TableCell<Member, String> call(TableColumn<Member, String> param) {
            TableCell<Member, String> cell = new TableCell<Member, String>() {
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                    System.out.println(item);
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);
                    ImageView imageview = new ImageView();
                    imageview.setFitHeight(TABLE_IMAGE_MEMBER_HEIGHT);
                    imageview.setFitWidth(TABLE_IMAGE_MEMBER_WIDTH);
                    if(item != null) {
                        imageview.setImage(new Image(item));
                        setGraphic(imageview);
                    } else {
                        if(!empty) {
                            imageview.setImage(new Image(ImageFiles.GENERIC_MALE.toString()));
                            setGraphic(imageview);
                        } else {
                            setGraphic(null);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            return cell;
        }
    };
    return  callback;
}
```

In Member object when Photo is null getter return Image corresponding a his gender. In this callback it seems that getter is not used. 
How can I acces member property in this case ??

@EDIT

In Member class :

```
public String getPhoto() {
    if (photo.getValue() != null && !photo.getValue().equals("")) {
        return photo.get();
    } else if (getGender().equals(Gender.F)) {
        return ImageFiles.GENERIC_FEMALE.toString();
    } else {
        return ImageFiles.GENERIC_MALE.toString();
    }
}
```

adding CellValueFactory :

```
this.simPhotoColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().photoProperty());
```

Comment: Getter? The code snippet you posted does not contain the string `get`!

Comment: you'are right  so when property is null.. I have null as item. In Member class I have getter for photo. So this is problem for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I was found the solution. My error that I was searching how set image in CellFactory. 
The response is to set custom CellValueFactory.

I was replaced this :

```
this.simPhotoColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().photoProperty());
```

by :

```
  this.memberPhoto.setCellValueFactory(getPhotoValueFactory());

private Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Member, String>, ObservableValue<String>> getPhotoValueFactory() {
    Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Member, String>, ObservableValue<String>> callback = param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().getPhoto());
    return callback;
}
```